# Can a train station and depot be built in the same city?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe

I’m playing Ticket to Ride: Europe with the 1912 expansion. Can a train station and a depot be placed in the same city?

Answer (score 4):

No, a depot can't be in same city as a station.  This is in the rules [here](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/de/img/720112-T2R1912-EN-2019.pdf)

> There can never be more than 1 Depot in any city. Once placed on the
> board, a Depot can never be moved nor removed (nor co-exist with a
> Station in Ticket to Ride Europe).